# telerik:RadGrid: How to get the row index based off a clientside event triggered by a column control

Tags: javascript, telerik, radgrid

There is a 4 column grid, in the second column there is a dropdown list whose client change event is wired to trigger some actions based on the value selected. Basically, the control in the 3rd column will be manipulated based off the ddl value and whether a checkbox in the last column is checked.

## RadGrid

```
  <telerik:RadGrid ID="theGrid" runat="server">
        <MasterTableView ClientDataKeyNames="ProductId" EditMode="InPlace">
            <Columns>
               <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ProductName" HeaderStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText="Product Name" UniqueName="ProductName" ReadOnly="true"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>


                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="ProductServices" HeaderText="QX Services">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                          <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="ddlProductServices" runat="server"  OnClientItemSelected="productServicesItemSelected"></telerik:RadDropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                 </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

               <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="IncludePublicRecordData" HeaderText="Include Public Record Data">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:CheckBox ID="IncludePublicRecordData" runat="server" Enabled="False" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:CheckBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
              </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

            <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="EnablePublicRecordData" UniqueName="hdnEligiblePublicRecordData" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Eligible Public Record Data">
          </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>

         </Columns>
      </MasterTableView>
      <ClientSettings AllowKeyboardNavigation="false" EnableRowHoverStyle="True">
         <Selecting AllowRowSelect="false" EnableDragToSelectRows="False" />
     </ClientSettings>
 </telerik:RadGrid>
```

## Actionable clientside event

I need to know which row is currently in play for this to work. Currently this wonky solution works but ONLY because there is 1 row in the table.

What I'm going to attempt, is spin throw the rows and match the id of the "sender" object to one in one of the cells and use the index of the loop. But that seems so bad and inconsistent (due to the nesting of objects). I'm sure telerik has an easier, cleaner way to accomplish this...thus my plea to the SO community.

```
  function productServicesItemSelected(sender, eventArgs) {

        try {
            const str = sender._uniqueId; 
          
            let parent = sender.get_parent();

            const item = eventArgs.get_item();
            const selectedValue = item.get_value() || "";

            console.log("You selected " + item.get_text() + "; with value " + item.get_value());

            let itemParent = item._parent;

            let theGrid = $find("<%=ProductServicesGrid.ClientID %>");
            if (theGrid) {
                let masterTable = theGrid.get_masterTableView();
                let rows = masterTable.get_dataItems();
                let rowIdx = 0;

                if (rows.length > 1) {
                    console.log("...finding rowIdx:");
                    
                    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        let row = rows[i];
                        let cellz = row._element.cells;
                        if (cellz) {
                            for (var j = 0; j < cellz.length; j++) {
                                var celll = cellz[j];
                                // match item uniqueId with that of each cell
                                console.log(celll);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                let currentRow = rows[rowIdx];
                let cells = currentRow._element.cells;
                // 
                let eligibleCheckbox = cells[3].firstElementChild.childNodes[0];
                let includeCheckbox = cells[2].firstElementChild;

                if (selectedValue === "QEWComp" || selectedValue === "none") {
  
                    // disable 
                    $(includeCheckbox).attr('disabled', true);
                    // uncheck 
                     $(includeCheckbox).prop("checked", false);

                 } else {
                     if (eligibleCheckbox.checked) {
                         $(includeCheckbox).attr('disabled', false);
                     } else {
                         $(includeCheckbox).attr('disabled', true);
                     }
                }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that I have done something similar is to pass in the Container.ItemIndex

```
OnClientItemSelected='<%# string.Format("productServicesItemSelected(this, {0}); return false;", Container.ItemIndex) %>'
```

The JavaScript function would look like

```
function productServicesItemSelected(sender, itemIndex) { }
```

To get the selected row that your dropdown was in you can use:

```
var theGrid = $find("<%=ProductServicesGrid.ClientID %>");
var masterTableView = theGrid.get_masterTableView();
// clear any previously selected rows
theGrid.clearSelectedItems();
// select the current row by index
masterTableView.selectItem(itemIndex);
var selectedItems = masterTableView.get_selectedItems();
 
if (selectedItems.length > 0) {}
```

This will give you the selected row and you can use functions off of selectedItems[0] to get data key values you have defined on the grid like productID

Hopefully this helps somewhat.